# Odoo11 - `create_invoices()` Error, Needs One Argument whereas Previosly Used with Two Arguments

Tags: python, odoo, erp, odoo-11

I am working for Odoo project of my company.

An engineer before me (now he resigned) made a Go script that launches periodically to create invoices from sales orders. This Go script works fine.

Now, we realize that creating invoice can be done through Odoo's Automated/Scheduled Actions as well.

My current task is to translate his Go script into Odoo's Automated Action.

But, I have a problem....

In his Go script there are codes like this:

```
param := []interface{}{
    c.cred.Db,
    c.uid,
    c.cred.Password,
    "sale.advance.payment.inv",
    "create_invoices",
    []int{
        paymentID,
    },
    map[string]interface{}{
        "context": map[string]interface{}{
            "active_id":    salesOrderID,
            "active_ids":   []int{salesOrderID},
            "active_model": "sales.order",
        },
    },
}
```

The codes are basically meant to work from model `"sale.advance.payment.inv"` and then call the method `create_invoices`.

With the first parameter is the payment object.
With the second parameter is a JSON/Python Dict of something exactly like this:

```
{
    'context':
    {
        'active_id'   :  so['id'],
        'active_ids'  : [so['id']],
        'active_model': 'sales.order'
    }
}
```

My Automated Action is like this:

```
paymentInAdvModel = env["sale.advance.payment.inv"]
paymentInAdv = paymentInAdvModel.create(
    {
        'advance_payment_method': 'delivered',
        'amount': 0,
    }
)

paymentInAdv.create_invoices(
    [paymentInAdv],
    {
        'context':
        {
            'active_id'   :  so['id'],
            'active_ids'  : [so['id']],
            'active_model': 'sales.order'
        }
    }
)
```

There is this error for Automated Action:

> ValueError: : "create_invoices() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given" while evaluating

Things to notice:

- It says that the method of `"create_invoices"` need only one parameter. I supplied two parameters, but the error said that I have three parameters inputted. I assume the other parameter is a Python's `self`.
- The only documentation I have is to look at Odoo GitHub repository in this link: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/search?q=create_invoices&unscoped_q=create_invoices

  - Which only refers to one function named `create_invoices` and it only takes one parameter.
- The Go script is working fine. But this error blocks me from converting Go codes into Python Odoo's Automated Action.

Anyone have solutions hence, I can use `create_invoices()` with the same parameter as the Go script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass list when you call create_invoice method and also you need to pass the context using with_context() method.

Try following code:

```
ctx = {
    'active_id'   :  so['id'],
    'active_ids'  : [so['id']],
    'active_model': 'sales.order'
}
paymentInAdv.with_context(ctx).create_invoices()
```

Hope this will help you.